# Failed to create a JVM with the requested environment

Tags: python, maven, java-11, pyimagej

I was trying to initialize imagej(imagej.init()) but this error comes everytime. I have tried everything but not able sort it out.

```
# Failed to bootstrap the artifact.

Possible solutions:
* Double check the endpoint for correctness (https://search.maven.org/).
* Add needed repositories to ~/.jgorc [repositories] block (see README).
* Try with an explicit version number (release metadata might be wrong).

Full Maven error output:
    [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
    [ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Failed to resolve version for net.imagej:imagej:pom:RELEASE: Could not find metadata net.imagej:imagej/maven-metadata.xml in local (/home/arrow/.m2/repository) @ line 8, column 29
    [ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for net.imagej:imagej-legacy:jar is missing. @ line 10, column 254
    [ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.scijava:scijava-config:jar is missing. @ line 10, column 464
    [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]   
    [ERROR]   The project net.imagej-BOOTSTRAPPER:imagej-BOOTSTRAPPER:0 (/home/arrow/.jgo/net.imagej/imagej/RELEASE/5dacb2d74cc139236f7db62ac3391755ef26a277311eab7c4c9f89d2892a0367/pom.xml) has 3 errors
    [ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failed to resolve version for net.imagej:imagej:pom:RELEASE: Could not find metadata net.imagej:imagej/maven-metadata.xml in local (/home/arrow/.m2/repository) @ line 8, column 29 -> [Help 2]
    [ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for net.imagej:imagej-legacy:jar is missing. @ line 10, column 254
    [ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.scijava:scijava-config:jar is missing. @ line 10, column 464
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
    [ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException

    ***Invalid Initialization: you may be using a primary endpoint that lacks pom-scijava as a parent***
    To keep all Java components at compatible versions we recommend using a primary endpoint with a pom-scijava parent.
    For example, by putting 'net.imagej:imagej' first in your list of endpoints.
    If you are sure you DO NOT want a primary endpoint with a pom-scijava parent, please re-initialize with 'add_legacy=False'.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/home/arrow/mambaforge/envs/pyimagej/lib/python3.8/site-packages/imagej/__init__.py", line 1202, in init
        raise RuntimeError("Failed to create a JVM with the requested environment.")
    RuntimeError: Failed to create a JVM with the requested environment.
```

not able to use imagej through pyimagej. It's working fine on google colab but not on my machine.

**here is the pom.xml file**

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.imagej-BOOTSTRAPPER</groupId>
    <artifactId>imagej-BOOTSTRAPPER</artifactId>
    <version>0</version>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies><dependency><groupId>net.imagej</groupId><artifactId>imagej</artifactId><version>RELEASE</version><type>pom</type><scope>import</scope></dependency></dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies><dependency><groupId>net.imagej</groupId><artifactId>imagej</artifactId><version>RELEASE</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>io.scif</groupId><artifactId>scifio-labeling</artifactId><version>0.3.1</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>net.imagej</groupId><artifactId>imagej-legacy</artifactId></dependency><dependency><groupId>net.imglib2</groupId><artifactId>imglib2-imglyb</artifactId><version>1.1.0</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>org.scijava</groupId><artifactId>scijava-config</artifactId></dependency></dependencies>
    <repositories><repository><id>scijava.public</id><url>https://maven.scijava.org/content/groups/public</url></repository></repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: The first thing which is showing up: `POM: Failed to resolve version for net.imagej:imagej:pom:RELEASE`. that tells me you have wrong versiosn in your pom file... please show the pom file..

Comment: here is the pom.xml file
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Wwt7TnFgVQ2v_QUKGLULbXzrC9-qvFIg?usp=sharing

Comment: It would help to post that here in the question...instead of using external resources...

Comment: i have added the pom file at the end of ques.

Comment: This: `Non-resolvable import POM: Failed to resolve version for net.imagej:imagej:pom:RELEASE: ` shows a problem...(DO NOT USE `RELEASE` as a version; it's imply wrong.) You must fix this first (Apart from that you should correctly format the posting...otherwise it's really hard to read...